# CMake include directories and enviroment variables in C++ project

Tags: c++, cmake

First timer on CMake. I am currently trying to create a visual studio 2013 solution (project) with CMake.

So i am facing 2 problems.

First one is that i use include_directories in my root cMakeLists.txt but instead of the directories to be included under the VC++ Directories tab they are included under C/C++ -> General -> Additional include directories .

The second problem is that i use an enviroment variable to include those directories , but instead of printing then in the Additional include directories as such : $(myVar)/lib/inc it prints it as a full path (e.g. C:/../lib/inc) and the end user won't have of course the same path as mine.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: you're correct indeed, my mistake.

Comment: you have to understand that CMake is generator, so you need not to share the generated visual studio solution, only directory with CMakeLists.txt and other users will generate own solution with CMake using your CMakeLists.txt. so you need not warry about paths in your generated solution.

Comment: I suppose your answer is about the second problem, it is supposed to be a framework so i am not looking to involve the use of CMake to the end user. I want the end user to receive solution and work upon it . :

Comment: in that case you have to choose native visual studio solution and do not use CMake, because CMake generates many service artifact and you will never get clean solution.

Comment: I am using CMake because it will involve later on support for Unix system's also. Anyhow i will try to surpass this issue. My trouble is what happens wrong with the include directories.

Comment: Projects generated by CMake are generally not relocatable, so you can't generate a project with CMake and then send that project to an end user. The end user has to run CMake to generate the project for themselves.

Comment: @Davelis4 first of all who said that the first your problem is issue? CMake has own rules how interprete own commands for each target.

Comment: Because that's the way it works with most users as far as i have searched. So Nobody said it.  What i said is that i am a noob and i am trying to figure how CMake works in order to implement it to my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer your questions to help you gain a better understanding of how CMake works.

> First one is that i use include_directories in my root cMakeLists.txt but instead of the directories to be included under the VC++ Directories tab they are included under C/C++ -> General -> Additional include directories .

This is just the way CMake generates Visual Studio Projects. I'm not aware of any way to change this.

> The second problem is that i use an enviroment variable to include those directories , but instead of printing then in the Additional include directories as such : $(myVar)/lib/inc it prints it as a full path (e.g. C:/../lib/inc) and the end user won't have of course the same path as mine.

To avoid ambiguities in the generated project CMake tends to resolve all paths to fully qualified paths. This (among other things) means that *CMake projects are not relocatable*. Which means projects generated by CMake are not intended to be moved around after they've been generated, and are definitely not intended to sent to other users for use on other computers.

What this means for you is this: if you use CMake all of your end users also must install and use CMake. If this is not possible or practical for your end users, then CMake isn't the solution for this particular project.